# Error al intentar instalar un paquete con Nuget en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin

Tengo un proyecto en Xamarin Forms y quiero consumir servicio desde una pagina externa. Estoy intentando instalar el paquete `Microsoft.Net.Http` para consumir dicho servicios y me da el siguiente error:

> No se pudo instalar el paquete 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. Está
>   intentando instalar este paquete en un proyecto que tiene
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0' como destino, pero el paquete no contiene
>   referencias de ensamblado o archivos de contenido compatibles con
>   dicho marco. Para obtener más información, póngase en contacto con el
>   autor del paquete. 0]

Comment: Si estás evaluando alternativas, RESTsharp es una muy buena http://restsharp.org/ Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

Esto ocurre porque `Microsoft.Net.Http` depende de otro paquete llamado `Microsoft.Bcl.Build`.

Para esto debes ir a ***Solución -> Administrar paquetes para la solución -> En la pestaña "Examinar"***

**Primero:** Instala el paquete `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` en su versión más reciente 1.0.21

**Segundo:** Después del primer paso, instala el paquete `Microsoft.Net.Http` en su versión más reciente 2.2.29

Comment: EXCELENTE, ME HA FUNCIONADO DE MARAVILLA ESTAMOS INTENTANDO CREAR UNA APLICACIÓN QUE CONECTE POR BLUETOOTH ARDUINO A APP XAMARIN, MAS REST API PARA VER DATOS DEL CONSUMO ENERGÉTICO

Comment: Jonatan, cara agradecer una respuesta no hay que poner otra y mucho menos en mayusculas... Si quieres agradecerselo , vota positivamente su respuesta